# Enable automatic formatting for Java in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: java, visual-studio-2015

I downloaded the [Java template](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bc561769-36ff-4a40-9504-e266e8706f93) for Visual Studio 2015, but it doesn't seem to have intelli-sense or format the code like it does with C, C++ and C#. It doesn't even mark error lines with red. It is basically just like notepad, but it compiles just fine.

Is there a way to enable that, or it is impossible?

Comment: I kind of doubt it. I'd use Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA - the latter is really good. But if you have some reason for using VS specifically, I'm not personally sure how to help. Best of luck.

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner I have had very frustrating experiences with Eclipse. The Eclipse interface and usability and most importantly the text editor is unacceptable comparing to my experiences with Visual Studio. Every option I am looking for I had to manually download some extension and change it myself or it doesn't exist and it feels like I am building Visual Studio myself. I will give `IntelliJ IDEA` a shot. Never heard of it before.

Comment: I hate Eclipse as well - but I've loved IntelliJ so far. If you're a student, also, it's free for the Ultimate Edition. Otherwise the Community Edition (which does everything you'd likely need anyways, except J2EE stuff out of the box) is free for life and perfectly good.

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner IntelliJ IDEA seems like a masterpiece compared to Eclipse. I tried both android and normal java apps project and it is feels like a very solid piece of software. Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Java Language Support](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bc561769-36ff-4a40-9504-e266e8706f93)  & [Java debugging and language support in Visual Studio for Android](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/11/06/java-debugging-and-language-support-in-visual-studio-projects-for-android.aspx)

Comment: Why hate Eclipse. Any issues?

Comment: @Loc Slow, bad interface, weird hotkeys, not intuitive. There are better IDEs out. But Eclipse might be good for some people. I know that a good amount of top developers use it. There is a whole [website](http://www.ihateeclipse.com/) dedicated to eclipse issues. That says a lot.

Comment: funny nobody mentioned [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) yet :/

Answer (score 1):

I cannot with authority say that it's impossible, but I've never heard of anyone using VS to do Java development.

Comment: Instead of Visual Studio, perhaps try [Visual Studio Code, which has Java support via Red Hat and Microsoft extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java).

Answer (score 0):

As proposed in [Beautify(Format) Java code in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42940091/beautifyformat-java-code-in-visual-studio-code)
you may take a look at [Language support for Java ™ for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java).

It will look like that:

[image]

Comment: Does this also apply to Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Normally yes, I didn't try. You just need to have access to the visualstudio-marketplace.